# Can I make a statement about how much larger of a delta a metric needs to be, such that a neutral conclusion become a significant one?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

Apologies for the convoluted title. Couldn't figure out a more elegant 1 sentence description.

Here are the details.

I have an experiment measuring a metric e.g. conversion rate, that concluded with a confidence interval straddling 0, and a p-value larger than the classic 0.05 threshold. This points to insufficient evidence to reject the null, a scenario I'm describing as a "neutral" result.

With the information I have from this experiment, is there anything wrong with me making the following claim?

- I can calculate the standard error from the confidence interval e.g. CI of [-0.5, 1.3] = SE of 0.9
- Can I claim that had this experiment resulted in an observed delta of 0.9, assuming S.E remains the same, my new C.I would be [0.0, 1.8] leading to a conclusion of statistical significance?

My instincts tell me there's a big flaw in this reasoning but I can't figure out where exactly.

Comment: I am not sure how you got a standard error of $0.9$ from the confidence interval.  I would have something half that.  Not that it affects your logic: in essence, you are saying that the rejection region would have been $(-\infty,-0.9]\cup[0.9,\infty)$ but you observed $0.4$ so did not reject.

Comment: Ah yes, you got the gist of what I was trying to convey. Your rejection region is correct.

Comment: One of the most practical ways to use such a result is to consider how much the CI needs to shrink around its center before it does not cover $0.$ Because that shrinkage would require both endpoints to come $0.5$ closer to the center and the width currently is $1.3-(-0.5)=1.8,$ the interval would have to be $(1.8-2\times 0.5)/1.8=0.8/1.8$ times as large. In an independent experiment with $k$ times as many observations, you can expect the confidence interval to be *c.* $1/\sqrt k$ times as large. Equating these two facts shows you need about $1/(0.8/1.8)^2\approx 5.1$ times as much data.

Comment: (Continued) Of course that analysis is freighted with many assumptions, tantamount to supposing a new data collection effort would yield approximately the same results (mean and variance) as before.  Nevertheless, notice how easy it is to carry such calculations: they can be helpful for quickly deciding whether it's worth continuing your efforts or for determining how much time and money you will eventually need to spend if you believe your current estimates are correct.

Comment: Thanks @whuber if you'd like to submit these points as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the top one.

Comment: @whuber Isn't this the margin of error calculation with the extra assumption that the effect as well as the standard error were estimated accurately in the first wave? And planning for detecting that effect or larger, rather than deciding what's the smallest effect (of practical interest) that they would want to detect.

Comment: @dipetkov It's close to that.  The implicit assumptions are that the width of the CI is inversely proportional to the square of the sample size and that the location and width of the original CI are good indications of what one would observe in the future.  When explaining this to clients I emphasize these assumptions, because sometimes the future holds surprises, and I inquire about any additional information that might help us anticipate future results. Sometimes they insist the current results are anomalous and choose to use theoretical projections for the design of the next study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

I don't think your approach makes any sense as the sampling should be robust. Focus on the statistical power of your result instead, which you can compute using e.g. [G*Power](https://www.psychologie.hhu.de/arbeitsgruppen/allgemeine-psychologie-und-arbeitspsychologie/gpower). If the power is too low, your sample is too small to confidently reject the hypothesis. If it is high enough, the effect might simply not exist.

## Long answer

I personally struggle with the notion of "this would be significant if the data was different", because I don't see the benefit of this. If your sampling method is not flawed, why should you assume significant changes from another sample? Instead, I would suggest focussing on the statistical power of your result.

Statistical power refers to the notion of type 1 and type 2 error. I'm not too familiar with the underlying theory, but you basically use your resulting sample size and effect size to compute the power, i.e. the chance of falling for a type 2 error when rejecting your hypothesis. If the power is too low, your sample size is too small to actually be able to detect the effect in the population. There's different conventions for when a power is acceptable. I know that .8 and .95 are commonly used in psychology, but the values really are subjective at the end of the day.

For me, illustrations really helped to get the point across. I'm using [G*Power](https://www.psychologie.hhu.de/arbeitsgruppen/allgemeine-psychologie-und-arbeitspsychologie/gpower) here, which is really handy for all kinds of power computations. If you find the concept of statistical power useful, I highly recommend you check it out. Now, on to the illustrations:

First, let's assume a fairly small effect in a correlation with a sample size of 100 and the common assumption of $\alpha = .05$. You can see that the resulting power of my experiment (bottom right of the screenshot) is only 0.25 (apologies, the "," is the German convention instead of "."). In the top-part, you see that our assumed distributions are highly overlapping and that our $\beta$ is very large, i.e. we have a high probability of running into a type-2 error when rejecting our hypothesis. Accordingly, our power $1-\beta$ is very small.

[image: Screenshot of G*Power post hoc power calculation for a correlation with a small effect and resulting overlapping normal distributions. Resulting power: 0.2589.]

Now, let's assume the same setting but with a much larger effect. You can see that the resulting power is approximately 0.99 and that the curves hardly overlap at all. So the probability of comitting a type 2 error when rejecting our hypothesis is almost negligible.

[image: Screenshot of G*Power post hoc power calculation for a correlation with a large effect and resulting non-overlapping normal distributions. Resulting power: 0.9964.]

Please note that this of course does not imply that we can say that our null hypothesis is actually true, but only strengthens the assumption that our hypothesis is not true.

Coming back to your question, the metric that you probably want to address is sample size. With a growing sample size, you can actually detect smaller effects, as the resulting distributions get narrower. To illustrate, I'm gonna reuse the previous example with a small effect size of 0.1 but a larger sample of 3000 instead of 100:

[image: Screenshot of G*Power post hoc power calculation for a correlation with a small effect and a large sample size with resulting non-overlapping normal distributions. Resulting power: 0.9999.]

You can see that the resulting power is again very high, even though the effect is still small. This is because the CI reduces with a larger sample size, which you have probably heard before. So what I would propose in your case is to compute the statistical power of your experiment and report this. You can say something like "the given sample is too small to reliably detect the assumed effect" if the power is too low and maybe compute a required sample size if the power is actually too low. If the power is high enough, I wouldn't beat around the bush and just accept that your hypothesis cannot be accepted.

Lastly, keep in mind that having too large sample sizes actually leads to $p$ hacking, as anything will become significant when the sample is large enough. This is a separate issue though and I feel like this post is way too long as it is, so I'm not going to dive into this.

I hope this helped! If there are any questions, please feel free to ask :)

Comment: Yes, I am in agreement with you that this way of "twisting" the results of the initial experiment to make the statement "If the measure was X instead, we would have been significant" feels wrong.

Comment: However, I'm not sure your expansion on statistical power sufficiently answers why the above statement is wrong. As a classic frequentist retort, could we not assume in a parallel universe where this experiment is repeated, with power ceteris paribus, we obtain a measured result with the same S.E, but just large enough that C.I is completely above 0. This would result in a conclusion that the experiment is stat sig.

So why can't we make a statement in this universe, that had the result been X, we would have declared stat sig?

Comment: The tangent on statistical power was not meant to disprove your statement but intended as a tip on what you could do instead. I don't see how your statement is wrong in a purely statistical way - if the CI does not cover 0, you can reject your H0 with the given probability. But what's the value of that? It's like instead of saying "People are not buying enough so we are not making a profit" you say "If people were buying more we would make a profit". I fail to see the benefit here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Fair points.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than theorizing what if the estimated effect were twice as big, you can plan the next experiment so that its standard error is twice as small. (For the experiment that's already over, there is nothing to do other than present the results clearly and truthfully.)

To make this concrete, let's suppose that you are working with a confidence interval of the form:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar{x} \pm z_{\alpha}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\bar{x}$ is the estimate and

- $z_{\alpha}$ is the critical value, $\sigma$ is the *standard deviation*, $n$ is the sample size
- $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is the *standard error*;
- $z_{\alpha}\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is the *margin of error*.

Here $z_{\alpha}$ is determined by the significance level $(1-\alpha)$100% and $\sigma$ is a property of the population under study. You probably want to keep $\alpha$ and $z_{\alpha}$ fixed, and it's hard to change $\sigma$.

But you do get to choose the sample size $n$. You can make the margin of error (the half-width of the confidence interval) as small as you want by increasing $n$. In your case, $\bar{x} = 0.4$ and $z_{\alpha}\sigma/\sqrt{n} = 0.9$, so the margin of error is more than 2 × the estimate; the sample wasn't large enough to estimate the effect very precisely.

And here is where planning for the next experiment comes in. If an effect size of 0.3 is the smallest effect size of practical interest, you'd want the margin of error to be less than 0.3. So you use the results from the concluded experiment to get an estimate $\hat{\sigma}$ of the standard deviation $\sigma$ and then you solve for $n$ in the formula $z_{\alpha}\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{n} < 0.3$.

PS: I deliberately choose the "smallest valuable" effect to be smaller than the effect observed in the pilot study. This is the effect that you would regret to miss as "non-significant" because the followup experiment wasn't large enough to detect it at the $(1-\alpha)$100% level.